# DependencyService.Get<ILogManager>().GetLog() System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, nlog

I am trying to execute Xamarin App.

I can build and deploy solutions on both Android and iOS devices. But when I am Debugging/running iOS App I am receiving an error
`**System.NullReferenceException:** 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'`
on
`private static ILogger logger = DependencyService.Get<ILogManager>().GetLog();` line

I have installed the latest version of the `Nlog` NuGet Package.

[image]

My ILogManager file is

```
namespace VolMobile.AppData.Interfaces
{
    public interface ILogManager
    {
        ILogger GetLog([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath]string callerFilePath = "");

        void Reload();

        void DeleteLog();
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

***update***

My NLogManager iOS file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.IO;
using NLog;
using NLog.Config;
using NLog.Targets;
using VolMobile.AppData.Interfaces;
using VolMobile.iOS.Logging;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(NLogManager))]
namespace VolMobile.iOS.Logging
{
    public class NLogManager : ILogManager
    {
        string logFile;
        LoggingConfiguration config;


        public NLogManager()
        {

            Reload();

        }



        public void Reload()
        {
            config = new LoggingConfiguration();

            var consoleTarget = new ConsoleTarget();
            config.AddTarget("console", consoleTarget);

            var consoleRule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, consoleTarget);
            config.LoggingRules.Add(consoleRule);
            //File logging level
            LogLevel llSetting = LogLevel.Off;
            IEnumerable<LogLevel> sysLevels = LogLevel.AllLevels;

            //default to trace at startup
            string currentLogLevel = "Trace";

            //load the app state if available
            if (App.AppState != null)
                currentLogLevel = App.AppState.AppSettings.LogLevel;// AppData.AppData.LogLevel;
            foreach (LogLevel ll in sysLevels)
            {

                if (currentLogLevel == ll.Name)
                {
                    llSetting = ll;
                }
            }

            var fileTarget = new FileTarget();
            string folder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments); //android.os.environment is the other option
            fileTarget.FileName = Path.Combine(folder, "Log.txt");

            fileTarget.Layout = "${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${callsite}|${appdomain}|${logger}|${threadid}|${message}|{exception:format=tostring}";

            config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);
            logFile = Path.Combine(folder, "Log.txt");



            var fileRule = new LoggingRule("*", llSetting, fileTarget);//LogLevel.Warn
            config.LoggingRules.Add(fileRule);



            LogManager.Configuration = config;
        }

        public void DeleteLog()
        {
            File.Delete(logFile);
        }

        // Services.Logging.ILogger
        //AppData.Interfaces.ILogger
        //public NLogLogger GetLog([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = "")
        //{
        //    string fileName = callerFilePath;

        //    if (fileName.Contains("/"))
        //    {
        //        fileName = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf("/", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) + 1);
        //    }

        //    var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(fileName);
        //    return new NLogLogger(logger, logFile);

        //}

        public AppData.Interfaces.ILogger GetLog([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = "")
        {
            string fileName = callerFilePath;

            if (fileName.Contains("/"))
            {
                fileName = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf("/", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) + 1);
            }

            var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(fileName);
            return new NLogLogger(logger, logFile);
        }
    }
}
```

The app is working perfectly fine on iOS, Andriod simulators, and Android Device only not on iOS devices.

Comment: is `DependencyService.Get()` returning null?  Or is it coming from `GetLog()`?  If it's the first, you need to review how your service is registered and figure out why the resolution is failing.  If it's the 2nd, then you need to debug your code to find the source of the null ref.

Comment: Are you following this guide: https://martynnw.wordpress.com/2016/10/16/logging-with-nlog-in-xamarin-forms/ ? (Think the attribute `[assembly: Dependency(typeof(NLogManager))]` is important)

Comment: @RolfKristensen Yes I am following that link and I have  `[assembly: Dependency(typeof(NLogManager))]` in my iOS NLogManager file.

Comment: @Jason I am trying to get what is returning error `DependencyService.Get()` or `GetLog()` by adding a breakpoint. But it is not letting me to step in. It is just returning that error and on the android side, there is no issue.

Comment: @Jason it is `GetLog()` function returning this error, I am trying to debug/resolve but getting success.

Comment: you didn't post any of the code for `GetLog` so there is not much we can do to help

Comment: @Jason I have updated the question please have a look.

Comment: one the last two lines in `GetLog` must be causing it.  If you can't get a breakpoint to work, at least add some exception handling or console logging to determine the source of the problem

Comment: @Jason It is not even reacher NLoggerManager file.

Comment: earlier you said that `GetLog()` causes the error - now you say it does not even get that far.  Again, are you **positive** that it is even resolving the class?  Put a `Console.Writeline` in the constructor to check.  Or break up the `DependencyService.Get()` into a separate line so you can verify that it is not returning null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241841/discussion-between-thehunter-shergill-and-jason).

Comment: @Jason I tested the same function in Android NlogManager when I step into it. It took me to the GetLog function. So I assumed it is would be GetLog() function.

Comment: Please don't assume things, actually test them to be sure.  It's difficult to help when you are giving inaccurate information because you're making false assumptions.  I'm not able to actually run your code, so I have to rely on the information you give

Comment: please compare the setup of the Dependency attribute in the two platform projects - the most likely problem is that it is setup correctly in one but not the other

Comment: @Jason I have compared them they are both identical code apart from  `using VolMobile.iOS.Logging;` and `namespace VolMobile.iOS.Logging`

Comment: have you ever determine, conclusively, if the `Get` is returning a null or not?  Since the constructor calls `Reload` there could be problems in that method too, and it has no exception handling or logging