# Data binding not working on iOS device xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, nlog

I am updating a Xamarin App it is working perfectly on Android devices, Android Simulator, and iOS simulator but Not working on iOS devices. I want to test it on the device before launching a new release on Appstore.

I am able to deploy on iOS devices.

The first issue I was facing was in NLogger returning `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'`

For Logging, I am following

> https://martynnw.wordpress.com/2016/10/16/logging-with-nlog-in-xamarin-forms/

tried a lot to resolve the issue did not succeed. so I commented NLogger for Now and used `Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);` just to track/see errors. Here I have raised a question about the NLogger issue.

> https://stackoverflow.com/q/71025867/8287839

After commenting NLogger App worked it opened the landing (login) page. But data binding is not working whatever I am filling in the fields it's not being set to the model all parameters are empty. Image paths are Null, Constant variables are null.
On the simulator data binding is working.

How can I resolve this? Do I need to change some kind of permissions or generate a certificate on `developer.apple.com`?

Here I have uploaded ViewModel, controller, view files.

> https://github.com/omshergill/MobileApp

Comment: I suggest you create a simple test app to see if it works first.

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT  okay I can try that first thank you

Comment: you need to post code that demonstrates what you are doing if you expect us to help you.

Comment: @Jason https://github.com/omshergill/MobileApp here i have uploaded some relative code.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].  Code should be posted inline, not just as a link to a repo.  And what you did post is not even a complete solution, so there is no way for us to compile and test it.